# Angular: How to detect javaScript input change

Tags: javascript, angular

I create an presentation service that detect inputs by id `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(test.element)).value = val;` and then this service change the values and it work;

I called this service in `app.component.ts` as action `this.presentation.start()`.

**My Problem**
When I set the value of inputs in components by this service, that component not detect the inputs value, how can I force components to define the value.

Comment: It's not a good idea to access directly the dom in an angular application, doing this `document.getElementById` is not a good idea.

Comment: I know and you are right , Actually it's just a challenge

Comment: There is a change event on input, have you used it, edit and add any relevant code that will clarify your question.